# Mongoose Update

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I can't update the status field in the document. can somebody please help? Thanks!
changing the default value is the issue.

i want the admin to be able to update the status of the applicant from pending to whatever option is chosen from the select options in the ejs form

this is in the controller:

```
 exports.postName = async(req, res, next)=>{
     const name = req.body.name;
    console.log(name)
     const pupil = new Pupil({
         name: name,
     });

    await pupil.save().then(updates=>{
         console.log(updates)
         res.redirect('/name');
     }).catch(error=>{
         console.log(error);
     });
 }
```

this also is from the controller:

```
 exports.postUpdatePupil = async (req, res, next)=>{        
    const status = req.body.status
             Pupil.updateOne(
                 {_id: req.params.id},
                {
                    $set: {'Pupil.$.status': status}
           
                },(err, result)=>{
                    if(err){
                        return next(err)
                    }console.log(result);
                }
            )
```

this is the model:

```
const UpdateSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    status: {type: String, default: "Pending"}
});

const update = mongoose.model('update', UpdateSchema);

module.exports = update;
```

Answer (score 1):

Model name should be "Pupil" and not "Update".

```
const PupilSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    status: {type: String, default: "Pending"}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Pupil', PupilSchema);
```

And you update like:

```
Pupil.updateOne(
   { _id: req.params.id },
   status // same as { status: status }
   (err, result) => {
      if (err) return next(err);
      console.log(result);
   },
);
```

Comment: Thanks Ok! I'll try it out, but why do I have to change It when I have the entire model in  a variable called 'update'?

Comment: You are doing `new Pupil()`, but you are not declaring the model called **Pupil** but **update**. If you want to make it work with your model "update", you will have to do `new update()`, `update.updateOne()`... That s not a good practice for a clean code!

Comment: Thanks . That's very useful.